# Determining the length of an expl3 sequence

Tags: expl3

Is there a function/command/macro that gives the *length* of an expl3 sequence? I know that you can do something like the code below but I thought that there would be a more direct way of doing this since you can pop items from either end of the sequence and, internally, the sequence probably does know its own length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_tmp_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmp_seq {1,2,3,4,5,6}

\int_new:N \l_my_int
\int_set:Nn \l_my_int {0}

\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmp_seq {% loop through the sequence and count its length
   \int_incr:N \l_my_int
}
\NewDocumentCommand\SequenceLength{}{
   The~sequence~has~length~\int_use:N \l_my_int
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \SequenceLength

\end{document}
```

As you might expect, this prints:

[image]

Comment: `\seq_count:N`?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `expl3` this is always the `count` of a variable, so you want `\seq_count:N` (*cf.* `\tl_count:N`, `\prop_count:N`, *etc.*).

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed this in the manual.

Comment: @Andrew Perhaps you were looking for `length`: we used to call it that, but something like a `prop` doesn't really have length, hence the name change.

Comment: You're being too kind: I read through the entire section and just missed it:)